# Is there a way to perform a DATEADD() with a range of increments in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, date, datediff

Looking for a shortcut to getting a column with a range of dates +/- 3 days of a specific date.  I haven't found an elegant shortcut.  My premise maybe off, I haven't found a way to have a range of values in the increment parameter of DATEADD() but this is the gist of what I am looking to do.

```
SELECT    
    DATEADD(dd, BETWEEN -3 AND 3, x.myDate)       [Dates]
FROM
    myTable x
```

I know that this doesn't work but wanted to know if there was an equivalent shortcut to get the desired dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To construct a date range you could use a tally table or row-constructor:

```
SELECT *,
       DATEADD(dd, s.c, x.myDate)       [Dates]
FROM myTable x
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (-3),(-2),(-1),(0),(1),(2),(3)) s(c);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1d88bd71b3730367a804987ac7c7542)**

Comment: This worked wonders, thank you, I use OUTER APPLY a lot but always forget about CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
DECLARE @targetDate DATETIME = target
SELECT    
    x.myDate [Dates]
FROM
    myTable x
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(dd, x.MyDate, @targetDate) BETWEEN 3 AND -3
```